# How to deal with the confliction between PHP-Markdown and MathJax?

Tags: javascript, latex, markdown

I use [PHP-Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) plugin in WordPress. In order to show the formula beautifully, I add some code to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
});
</script>
```

But something wrong happens. Once my formula contains at least two underlines, the MathJax doesn't work. Such as `$$P_1, P_2$$`, and the words between the two underlines will be transformed to italic.

The formula will be transformed by PHP-Markdown first, and it can't be transformed by MathJax again.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a real answer, but have you tried [PHP-markdown-extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#em) (by the very same Michel Fortin)?

At least for me (using Mark Jaquith's [markdown-on-save plugin](https://github.com/markjaquith/markdown-on-save)) your example is not a problem.

But Markdown-extra is not perfect either and I've seen some other quirks with respect to emphasis, e.g.  Let $(y_n)_{n\in \omega}$ enumerate ${ x_i: i \in \bigcup_{n\in \omega} A_n} $ will trip it up.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use markdown-on-save and it works well. :)